# Angular 2+ One way data binding from view target to data source

Tags: angular, angular2-databinding

In my angular application, I have a  element that allows a user to set a description value. I want that value to be acceccable in the Data Source. I got this to work using 2-way data binding, as shown below:

```
<textarea id="MediaDescription" name="description" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="description"></textarea>
```

However, given my use case, 2-way data binding is unnecessary here. While the View Model needs to be able to update the Data Source, the opposite is not true.

I tried doing this using `(ngModelChange)`, but this doesn't seem to get called (I tested this by outputting the value via the `OnChanges()` method in the Data Source).

How can I best re-write this code such that my `<textarea>` value is only bound from the View Source to the Data Source, not the other way around?

Comment: Use reactive model instead of template model.

Comment: @Indrakumara How would reactive forms help to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really dont need `ngModel` here. Instead you can listen for `change` event

```
<textarea id="MediaDescription" name="description" class="form-control" (change)="description = $event.target.value"></textarea>
```

Note : `(change)` event is triggered only when `text-area` element looses the focus. This is the limitation.

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-one-way-binding?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: Thank you, this worked! Out of curiosity though, how come `(change)` is getting fired here but `(ngModelChange)` isn't?

Comment: Simple, because you don't have `ngModel` registered. `(ngModelChange)` wont work without `ngModel`

Answer (score 1):

To update the data source every time the `textarea` content changes, without using data binding, you can apply the `ngModel` directive by itself to allow `(ngModelChange)` to be triggered:

```
<textarea name="description" ngModel (ngModelChange)="description = $event" ...></textarea>
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iftkog) for a demo.

Comment: Exactly! That is what I mentioned in a comment on my answer with a negative statement.